# Angular service cant getting the rest api infomation

Tags: angular, typescript, rest

I am new to angular while consuming the data Form rest API. I am getting the following errors

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient , HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CountriessService {

  constructor(private httpclient: HttpClient )  {}

  public getContries():any{
    this.httpclient.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all") .pipe(map(response=>{
    return response.json();
    }));
  }
}
```

1.expected onespace after colon in call-signaturetslint(typedef-whitespace)

2." should be 'tslint(quotemark)

3.Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(2339)

4.(parameter) response: Object

Answer (score 0):

```
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CountriesService {
  constructor(private httpclient: HttpClient) {}

  public getContries(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpclient.get<any>('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all');
  }
}
```

1 and 2 are tslint errors. The first being a space too much after the constructor I believe, the second one is that it's set to use single quotes, and not double quotes. You had double quotes around your url. TSlint is used to have a consistent coding style throughout your project and among contributors. You can change the defaults by editing the `tslint.json`

3 is the `.json()` call. Since angular 4 the `HttpClient` has replaced the `Http` module, and internally calls `.json()`, so this no longer exists on the response from the `.get()` call.

4 You should set a generic value for the return type.

Better would be to use an appropriate IDE, which will give you decent warnings while writing and a bit more research about this errors would have pushed you in the right direction, and with it, configure a linter like prettier to have your code formatted according to the rules upon save.